# Just in time prize winning algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I'm building a contest where you can win prizes by opening boxes. Whatever the box is open, i just send a request to the server to test if the user won something. Since this contest is not a "Register and we'll draw a winner after some time" type of contest, i'm a bit puzzled at what algorithm i should be taking to calculate chances to win.

I've devised in an excel spreadsheet what i call a progressive winning algorithm in the form of:

```
([Number of prizes left] / [Prizes i should have left at this time of contest]) / 4
```

Which gives me a rough percentage change of winning an item off the pool of remaining items around 25%. If there are many winners within a close timespan, the algorithm should automatically lower the chances of winning while going in the opposite direction if the scenario is different.

What i'm afraid of is that not all my items will be drawn by the end of the contest because it's a linear calculation of expected gifts left or i'm afraid that, by chance, most of my prizes will be won after only half of the contest (and by chance i mean that lots of player get truly great random odds and keep winning)

So my question is, how should i tackle this kind of scenario, what are already known methods for this and please keep it simple, i'm no mathematician nor statistician.

---

**Variables to take into account**

- 100 prizes to give out total
- Contest lasts five whole days
- Unknown number of participants
- Unknown participation rule but will probably be once per day based on a unique credential such as an e-mail address.
- It's an online contest where a user opens a virtual box, nothing physical

Comment: So, you have a fixed number of prizes to give out, an unknown number and rate of contestants trying over a fixed period of time? And is this some sort of physical box they walk up to or is it online somehow? Is the "box" on a website?

Comment: Added an edit to answer your question

Comment: "once/day per unique email-address" So anyone can participate as many times as they want? You know it's trivial to setup email accounts right?

Comment: Voting to close as this is a statistics question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're thinking about it kind of backwards.  Rather than calculating an individual player's odds, it's much simpler to randomly distribute the *time* between winners.  For example, say you have 10 prizes, and the contest lasts an hour.  Randomly generate 10 numbers between 1 and 3600.  That gives a timestamp in seconds since the start of the contest.  The first player to open the box after that time wins the prize.

Assuming a relatively steady stream of customers, that distributes the prizes fairly, effectively increases the odds the longer it has been since a winner, automatically adjusts the odds for the number of players, and ensures all the prizes are distributed.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps if I'm in such a contest I should try to open my prize a bit before most contestants are likely to wake up.

Answer (score 1):

I created an algorithm for something similar recently which might be of help -- I'll try to tailor it to your scenario:

You have 100 prizes to give away in 5 days, so divide the total time (5 days) into 100 time-slots.

At some point in time during each time-slot, a prize should become available to be won. So, pick random numbers between 0 and 1 to map to each time-slot interval (0 being the beginning of a slot, 1 the end) and this will be the time within each slot a prize will become winnable.

As time progresses, new prizes will become winnable. If people haven't been playing, then there will be more winnable prizes in the pool; when these run out, prizes will go back to becoming winnable at the regular schedule of one per slot.

I varied things in my application by drawing the times things became available within a time-slot from a normal distribution so that things were more likely to happen near the middle of the slot. You might want to take a different approach and vary the sizes of the time-slots during the contest so that they're not all the same length (e.g. more smaller slots in the middle of the 5 days to make a higher concentration of the prizes become available during that time).